# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (initialization failure)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-6.1

I have deployed my application in websphere server and it was working fine last week.

Class files and configuration files are not changed after that, but now when I try to access the application I get the error

I am not able to understand why suddenly the initialization failure is occuring.

I am not sure whether the issue is due to some problem in websphere server?

```
[14-02-14 13:04:40:295 IST] 00000039 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: PCUSRCAASLogonServlet. Exception thrown : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.library.Debug (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:132)
    at com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.library.USRUserAutherization.getSSOID(USRUserAutherization.java:109)
    at com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.control.user.PCUSRCAASLogonServlet.performTask(PCUSRCAASLogonServlet.java:85)
    at com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.control.user.PCUSRCAASLogonServlet.doGet(PCUSRCAASLogonServlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1095)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:569)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1461)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
[14-02-14 13:04:40:299 IST] 00000039 WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[PCUSRCAASLogonServlet]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.library.Debug (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:132)
    at com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.library.USRUserAutherization.getSSOID(USRUserAutherization.java:109)
    at com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.control.user.PCUSRCAASLogonServlet.performTask(PCUSRCAASLogonServlet.java:85)
    at com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.control.user.PCUSRCAASLogonServlet.doGet(PCUSRCAASLogonServlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1095)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:569)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1461)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't remove a dependency?

Answer (score 2):

According to your stacktrace,
check this line
at `com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.library.USRUserAutherization.getSSOID(USRUserAutherization.java:109)`
you can find the clue.

Comment: The Debug class is used at that line. But I do not find any problem in code

Answer (score 1):

The JAR containing `com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.library.Debug` is missing on the runtime classpath, not much else to say really, just check if your compile and & runtime classpaths match up.

Answer (score 0):

I have restarted the server in debug mode and checked for the issue and it started working. This is very strange

Comment: Can you share with us where the jar is typically located that contains `com.klm.solution.cargo.webpearl.library.Debug` ?  Is it in your WEB-INF/lib directory or is it outside of your application, for example in a directory for a WebSphere shared library?  If so, is it possible this jar was manipulated / updated without any changes to your application?